# Open circuit showing 1-15MΩ of resistance on multimeter

Tags: sensor, relay, dc

I'm trying to understand a phenomenon I observed while troubleshooting a system.
There are airflow sensors with wires connected to common and normally open so that the circuit closes when air is flowing. The sensors appear to be working as expected, however, when the circuit is open, my multimeter shows fluctuating resistance of about 1-15MΩ at the end of the wires connected to the sensors and ~50ft in length. I've checked the wires by disconnecting from the sensor and checking continuity. I've checked the sensor directly and am getting an open loop as expected. I'm getting the same results with two multimeters.

Any ideas of what I could check or any explanations of what may be happening would be appreciated.

Comment: 15 mega ohms is high enough to practically open circuit for most things. There just might be some coupling over the length of such long wires

Comment: Most likely EMI NOISE from unbalanced wires causing slight rectification leakage current.  ADD an RF cap to snub noise with series R. There are other ways.

Comment: Another possibility is electrical leakage between the wires if moisture has gotten into them at some point. That could lead to corrosion of the wires and eventual failure even if the switches and other circuitry is unaffected.

Comment: Spider webs, mouse urine, bug stuff, dust / contamination, ... . Clean around switch connectors as well as able. Note change of resistance (if any) as you clean.